# Why Google play service for ar isn't compatible with Vivo IQOO devices

Tags: android, augmented-reality

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3UKx.jpg)

How to resolve this?? Is there a way to enable AR cores in a android device?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Not all devices have the hardware to support it.  Also, not all devices pay Google for access to all of their stuff (you know Google services and apps like Maps and Play Store aren't free to the OEM, right?).  ARCore just won't work on all devices.